# Use CLion2018 or VS2015 to build C project without dependency

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, compilation, dependencies, clion

I have a `c++` application built in *Visual studio 2015*, It seems `c++` apps have need *visual c++ 2015* (In my case) to be installed (on targeted windows version). Then i decided to convert my `c++` source to `c` and use *CLion 2018* for build this project. It has no error but the output executable has *visual c++ 2015* (It says: vcruntime140.dll is missing) dependency again. Here is my questions:

1. Does C written executable's have any external dependencies ? What are those dependencies ?
2. Im new to CLion2018, How to build c projects to work without dependency on all windows versions and architectures ?
3. Is still any way to use VS2015 to create and build c projects ? (Already tried changing *compile as:* option to `/TC` and changing extensions to `.c`. Build was successful but Output has *VCRUNTIME140.dll* error).

Note1: Both output files (In CLion and VS) are working on windows 7,8.1,10 with  *visual c++ 2015* installed. And both have "*VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing*" error on raw windows 7,8.1,10 without *visual c++ 2015* installed.

Note2: Don't want to pack those dll's with my file, Or installing vc++ 2015.

Comment: Don't know how to do that in CLion, but in VisualStudio you can configure your project to `statically` link the runtime.

Comment: @CannedMoose Why a `C` file even need vc++ ?

Comment: I think it is because in VS2015 you have to make .c files in a c++ project template and a `Platform Toolset` is forcibly is set

Comment: CLion is an IDE without its own compiler. If you haven't installed something else, it will likely use VC to compile the sources.